# 500 Internal server when trying to insert data when calling through ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, error-handling

I am getting information off a form and serializing it to then submit the string and deserialize it in the php side, all the information is being recieved correctly from the form to the script but the query to insert the data into the table creates a 500 internal server error. not sure why

here is the HTML

```
<form role="form" id="reportForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email1">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="name" placeholder="Your name...">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email1">Page Link:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pagelink" name="pagelink" placeholder="page link...">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="status">
              <option val="bug" name="bug">Bug</option>
              <option val="issue" name="issue">Issue</option>
              <option val="issue" name="issue">Approved</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>What's going on?</label>
            <textarea name="msg" id="sit" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
      <button type="button" id="subm" class="btn btn-default">Report</button>
    </form>
```

here is the javascript:

```
$("#subm").click(function(){
        var ticket = $("#reportForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"php/create_report.php",
          data:"form=" + ticket,

          success: function(data){

              $("alert-success").fadeIn();
              alert(data);
          },
          error: function(ajaxrequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

              $("alert-danger").fadeIn(500);
          }
        });

    })
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';

$name = $_POST['form'];

parse_str($name, $form_data);

$name = $form_data['name'];
$link = $form_data['pageLink'];
$status = $form_data['status'];
$desc = $form_data['msg'];


mysqli_select_db($mysqli_connection, "mailings_members");
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT into `bugs` (`ticket_author`, `ticket_link`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_message`) VALUES('$name', '$link','$status', '$desc' "))

if(!$query){
    die('Invalid query:' . mysql_error());
}else{
    echo 'Bam! major ownage';
}
```

?>

Some help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Check your error log, and enable PHP error logging if not already in place.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but please escape those variables or use prepared statements, sql-injections are bad!

Comment: You have a `)` in the wrong place and therefore a syntax error; -1. And you have bigger problems.

Comment: Don't take the serialized querystring and add it to another string before you send it with ajax, just send the original string and you don't need parse_str !

Comment: $query = mysqli_query("INSERT into `bugs` (`ticket_author`, `ticket_link`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_message`) VALUES('$name', '$link','$status', '$desc' "))
A misplaced double quote at end-
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT into `bugs` (`ticket_author`, `ticket_link`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_message`) VALUES('$name', '$link','$status', '$desc' )")

Comment: Please provide us with the error log of the server. If your on nginx then ude the `debug` option to log errors related to cgi/fcgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT into `bugs` (`ticket_author`, `ticket_link`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_message`) VALUES('$name', '$link','$status', '$desc' "))
```

End your VALUES list with `)` and end the whole function call with `;`

```
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT into `bugs` (`ticket_author`, `ticket_link`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_message`) VALUES('$name', '$link','$status', '$desc')");
```

Also, mysqli do not use the `mysql_error()` function (its deprecated with the rest of the  mysql_* functions), check http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php for the mysqli version of the error function.

Do not forget to escape the variables that you get from the client either, those can contain pretty much anything. You do not want to open up to sql injections.
Either use the escape function provided in mysqli or use the mysqli prepared statements (I would really recommend this!).

*Edit:*

You are missing the $link parameter in the query:

```
function mysqli_query ($link, $query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {}
```

If the 'mysqli_connection' variable is a mysqli object, Try:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli_connection, "INSERT into `bugs` (`ticket_author`, `ticket_link`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_message`) VALUES('$name', '$link','$status', '$desc')");
```

Is it possible that you just recently migrated from mysql_* to mysqli?

Comment: I corrected the syntax errors at the end of the query, but I am still getting the 500 internal server error

Comment: Do you get an internal server error if you fetch the page from the browser?

Comment: I'm kinda guessing now, cause I think most syntax errors are corrected now (You should get a good PHP IDE to help you with syntax errors while writing code). How do you connect to the database? Whats in the 'connection.php' file you include?
Also, as stated in one of the comments, check your logs, the server will most likely have put some info there.

Comment: I finally got the query to work, it was the query quoting that was making it crash, I corrected it as your edit said, and it solved the problem, Thank you very much, I will pay more attention to the detail in PHP... I use Sublime text, any recommendation on addons for php coding?  Thanks again for the help

Comment: Happy to help, glad you got it to work. I personally recommend PHPStorm by Jetbrains, it cost, but its by far the best PHP IDE there is (in my opinion). It could be worth checking out netbeans for a free IDE that works quite well with php too. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery serialize() already doing the url for you.

```
$("#subm").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"php/create_report.php",
          data:$("#reportForm").serialize(), // here you are sending all the params

          success: function(data){

              $("alert-success").fadeIn();
              alert(data);
          },
          error: function(ajaxrequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

              $("alert-danger").fadeIn(500);
          }
        });

    })
```

Now you have to alter your php code accordingly to the correct post request.

Comment: I recieve the information perfectly and I am escaping the variables to prevent sql injection, but still I am getting the 500 internal server error when trying to log data into the table, any suggestions on what to do with the php ?